# Data Table Always getting empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

I am trying to display report in mvc web application using rdlc. I have created data set and data table. but now report viewer always reloading continuously. when i try to figure out the problem i found this issue.

Here C# Code

```
private DataTable GetData(DateTime sdate, DateTime edate,string user,string sp_name)
            {
                DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
                string ConStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetBalanceSheet_CurrentUser", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = sdate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = edate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Uid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;

                    SqlDataAdapter oSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    oSqlDataAdapter.Fill(oDataTable);
                }
                return oDataTable;

            }
```

Here Sql Stored Procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- GetBalanceSheet_CurrentUser '2017-09-12' ,'2017-11-12' ,'ab0eb318-de5f-4f13-a80b-7a95f678ad8a'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBalanceSheet_CurrentUser]
    @SDate DateTime,@EDate DateTime,@Uid VarChar(MAX)
AS

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TEMP1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP2

DECLARE @UserId VarChar(MAX)
SELECT @UserId = @Uid

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) RNo,Description,Date,Amount,ForUser,CreatedUser,Status,ApprovedBy
    INTO #TEMP1
    FROM (

            SELECT PEDM.ProjectExpenditureDescription AS Description , PEDM.ExpendedDate As Date,PEDM.ProjectExpenditureCost As Amount, ANU1.UserName As ForUser,ANU1.UserName As CreatedUser,PEDM.ApprovedStatus As Status,ANU2.UserName As ApprovedBy 
            FROM ProjectExpenditureDetailsModel PEDM
            JOIN AspNetUsers ANU1
            ON ANU1.Id = PEDM.CreatedUser
            JOIN AspNetUsers ANU2
            ON ANU2.Id = PEDM.ApprovedBy
            WHERE PEDM.IsActive = 1
            AND PEDM.IsDelete = 0
            AND PEDM.Rejected = 0
            AND PEDM.CreatedUser = @UserId
            UNION ALL
            SELECT OMDM.ObtainedMoneyDescription As Description,OMDM.ObtainedDate As Date,(OMDm.ObtainedMoneyAmount *-1) As Amount, ANU3.UserName As ForUser,ANU4.UserName As CreatedUser,OMDM.ApprovedStatus,ANU5.UserName As ApprovedBy
            FROM ObtainedMoneyDetailsModel OMDM
            JOIN AspNetUsers ANU3
            ON ANU3.Id = OMDM.ForUser
            JOIN AspNetUsers ANU4
            ON ANU4.Id = OMDM.CreatedUser
            JOIN AspNetUsers ANU5
            ON ANU5.Id = OMDM.ApprovedBy
            WHERE OMDM.IsActive = 1
            AND OMDM.IsDelete = 0
            AND OMDM.Rejected = 0
            AND OMDM.ForUser = @UserId
        )A
ORDER BY Date

SELECT RNo,Description,Convert (varchar(20),Date,103) AS ConvertedDate,Date,Amount,SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY RNo) AS Balance,ForUser,CreatedUser,Status,ApprovedBy
INTO #TEMP2
FROM #TEMP1

SELECT RNo,Description,ConvertedDate,Date,Amount,Balance,ForUser,CreatedUser,Status,ApprovedBy
FROM #TEMP2
WHERE Date Between @SDate AND @EDate
```

When I execute program sql profiler indicates it hits successfully. but when i return result to data table its always getting empty.

Comment: Just for clarification, does "empty" mean that the DataTable contains no rows? How about columns? AFAICT your code looks fine, so I am suspecting the last query is not returning any rows. Have you executed the SP manually?

Comment: You are getting an exception probably due to the connection string being wrong or the credentials.  The "using" blocks are hiding the exception.  I prefer to use try/catch blocks instead of using.  The try/catch you can actually report an exception while the using unless you test for DataTable containing no rows you do not know you have an error.

Comment: @MikeMat Yes I have executed sp manually using same parameters. it is showing 10 records.but when i call through my c# code its hitting but sql data adapter always empty like {}

Comment: @jdweng Okay i'll try

Comment: @ThusharaHettigoda : Thanks for the info. What about the other question? You do not even get columns in the DataTable? In that case like @sepupic said, you should check the parameters being passed as you intended. You could replace the select query with `select @SDate as sdate, @EDate as edate, @Uid as uid` or something like that, so that in the DataTable you can actually see the parameters you are sending

Answer (score 0):

> I have executed sp manually using same parameters. it is showing 10
>   records.but when i call through my c# code its hitting but sql data
>   adapter always empty like {}

Do you execute your sp manually under the **same account**?

Your procedure uses `datetime` parameters but the literals for this parameters that you are passing in are **language dependent**.

Instead, you should pass them in language independent format `yyyymmdd` (without any separator)

Now, your login language is different from the default login of your application, this cause the date literals to be interpreted differently.

Here is an example to show you the problem. First execute it as it is, then comment `set language us_english` and uncomment `set language British;`

```
declare @t table (dt datetime);
insert into @t values ('20171001'), ('20171101'); -- added 1st oct + 1st nov

--set language British; 
set language us_english;

declare @SDate datetime ='2017-09-12',  @EDate datetime = '2017-11-12';

select *
from @t
WHERE dt Between @SDate AND @EDate;
```